# Change AppBar Title according to the appearance of ListView item

Tags: flutter, mobile

How to change AppBar Title according to the appearance of ListView item, I used inview_notifier_list to check the appearance of item but when placing inview_notifier_list inside SingleChildScrollView it works incorrectly

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried?

Comment: InViewNotifierList already have its own scrolling mechanism, so you don't have to use SingleChildScrollView

Comment: I want to have many Widgets on the screen, one of them is InViewNotifierList

Comment: Check out this package  sticky_and_expandable_list. [link](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_and_expandable_list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InViewList` only works if you let it use its own `ScrollController`. If you would like to show a `ImageSlideshow` at the top of the list, you can do so by adding it to the top of the list like this:

```
InViewNotifierList(
    isInViewPortCondition: (double deltaTop, double deltaBottom, double vpHeight) {
      return deltaTop < 20 && deltaBottom > 20;
    },
    // count of your items + 1
    itemCount: 10 + 1,
    builder: (context, i) {
      // Return the ImageSlideshow if it's the first item
      if (i == 0) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ImageSlideshow(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 200,
            initialPage: 0,
            indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
            indicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            autoPlayInterval: 3000,
            isLoop: true,
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Container(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Container(color: Colors.orange),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      // Make up for increasing the itemCount by 1 by decrementing i
      i--;
      return InViewNotifierWidget(
        id: '$i',
        builder: (context, isInView, child) {
          if (isInView) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              yourMethodToUpdateTitleWithIndex(i);
            });
          }
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
            child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Item $i"),
                )),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  )
```

BTW: The code is tested and fully functional.

Feel free to reach out if you need any more help with implementing the solution :)